# Emacs init file cannot open load file OS X

Tags: emacs, init, haskell-mode

I am trying to add `haskell-mode` to emacs, but I run into the error: `cannot open load file`.

This is what I've done...

First I downloaded the tar file for `haskell-mode` version 2.4 from here : http://projects.haskell.org/haskellmode-emacs/

After doing so, I have a directory full of mode and modules called `haskell-mode-2.4` in my `/Users/username/Downloads/...`.

The next step, I added this to my `~/.emacs.d/init.el` (Note: I also tried adding it to my ~/.emacs as well) as specified here...http://doc.gnu-darwin.org/haskell-mode/installation-guide.html :

```
(load "/Users/username/Downloads/haskell-mode-2.4")
(add-hook 'haskell-mode-hook 'turn-on-haskell-doc-mode)
(add-hook 'haskell-mode-hook 'turn-on-haskell-indent)
```

But after doing all this, I get an error: `cannot open load file`.

Why is this so? Could it be that my emacs version does not support the `haskell-mode`?

Comment: I realize I may have posted quite a few questions in the past hour, but it is imperative that I figure all this out. I keep getting errors even though I feel like I follow all the instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
(load "/Users/username/Downloads/haskell-mode-2.8.0/haskell-site-file")
```

Also, I'd suggest moving from Downloads to a different folder, but that's off topic ;)

Comment: Yes it works. I didn't realize I had to add `haskell-site-file`, any idea what its for, or what it is?

Comment: @Bolboa A site file is the local elisp for doing a thing (I think) - basically the source code for a package

Comment: Yes :)  Basically, it is the main file for a package.